# Using Playwright for Python, how to I read the content of an input box

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

In a website I'm automating, I have an input box that is disabled.

On the website it shows a number, like "1" and has other elements to change the value.

```
<input data-v-a6368fd8="" id="base-amount-input-211" max="10" name="Counter" disabled="disabled" type="number" class="amount-input__number amount-input__number--active">
```

When I query the element like

```
handle = page.querySelector('//input[starts-with(@name, "Counter")]')
```

I get a result for the handle.

When I try readling the handle content

```
handle.innerText() 

handle.innerHTML()
```

are both empty ('')

How can I access the current input value?

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to simply use the `getAttribute()` method of the `elementHandle` to retrieve the value:

```
handle = page.querySelector('//input[starts-with(@name, "Counter")]')
value = handle.getAttribute("value")
```

Answer (score 2):

For input elements, the `element.value` returns the filled in content. You can use `page.evalOnSelector` to run JS in the page against this selector and get the value.

```
selector = '//input[starts-with(@name, "Counter")]'
value = page.evalOnSelector(selector, "(element) => element.value")
```

Comment: for python it is page.eval_on_selector

Answer (score 2):

Currently, although arjunattam's answer still works, albeit with `evalOnSelector()` being replaced with `eval_on_selector()`, the most simple way to do this is with the `input_value()` function:

```
handle = page.query_selector('//input[starts-with(@name, "Counter")]')
value = handle.input_value()
```

buddemat's answer does not work and should not be used.